# как выбрать один из нескольких чекбоксов при помощи Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium

В моей автоматизации есть список чекбоксов в сайте из которых мне нужно выбрать определенный. Проблема в том что чекбокс и его текст являются раздельными элементами таблицы. И к примеру чтобы достать бокс у которого номер "994655439" мне нужен именно его **Xpath**, но таблица генерирует разные числа при каждом запуске.

Знаю про `find_element_by_xpath("//*[text() = "994655439"]")` , но он обращается снова ж к этому номеру в списке если он имеется, а мне нужен клик по его чекбокс элементу. Кто нибудь делал подобный финт?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<tr class="n-grid__row bi-focus-element-wrapper__ng" data-row-index="1" data-row-data="$view.rows[1]" ng-class="$view.getRowClass($view.rows[1])" ng-style="$view.getRowStyle($view.rows[1])"><td class="n-grid__td n-grid__status" data-column-index="0" ng-class="$view.columns[0].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[0].getCell($view.rows[1])})" ng-attr-style="{{$view.columns[0].design.style({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[0].getCell($view.rows[1])})}}" style="background-color:#00FF00 !important;">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[0].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[0].getValue($view.rows[1])"></div>
</td><td class="n-grid__td n-grid__select" data-column-index="1" ng-class="$view.columns[1].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[1].getCell($view.rows[1])})">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[1].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[1].getValue($view.rows[1])"><span class="n-check-checkbox"></span></div>
</td><td class="n-grid__td" data-column-index="2" ng-class="$view.columns[2].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[2].getCell($view.rows[1])})">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[2].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[2].getValue($view.rows[1])">994955454</div>
</td><td class="n-grid__td" data-column-index="3" ng-class="$view.columns[3].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[3].getCell($view.rows[1])})">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[3].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[3].getValue($view.rows[1])">Федеральная</div>
</td><td class="n-grid__td" data-column-index="4" ng-class="$view.columns[4].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[4].getCell($view.rows[1])})">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[4].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[4].getValue($view.rows[1])"></div>
</td><td class="n-grid__td" data-column-index="5" ng-class="$view.columns[5].design.classes.cell({row: $view.rows[1], cell: $view.columns[5].getCell($view.rows[1])})">
  <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[1]" data-cell="$view.columns[5].getCell($view.rows[1])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[5].getValue($view.rows[1])">Обычный</div>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: добавьте код пары строк таблицы, с чекбоксами и текстом

Comment: @Эникейщик предупреждаю у вас будет срыв башки ибо сайт состоит из непонятного говнокода

Comment: а чекбокс тут есть? что-то браузер чекбокс не показывает

Comment: @Эникейщик так точно вот сам чекбокс, ``` <div class="n-grid__text" data-row="$view.rows[0]" data-cell="$view.columns[1].getCell($view.rows[0])" ps-grid-bind-element="$view.columns[1].getValue($view.rows[0])"><span class="n-check-checkbox"></span></div>```